# discord.py Send a message through a command that after a set time counts how many have “voted” for a reaction (normal emoji)

Tags: discord.py

I've been trying for days (and even asked without success) to have reactions count on messages. The command I am working on is that of a vote that after a certain time automatically writes the results by precisely counting how much one reaction was voted over another.
I would like to use custom emojis but I can't and even trying with the normal ones I don't even count them and I don't really know what to do.
This here is the code that I used for testing if it is possible I would like to know how to solve the problem also with the addition of custom emojis.

```py
@client.command(aliases=["cr"])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def conteggio_reazioni(ctx, *, proposta):
    message = await ctx.send(proposta)
    favore = get(message.reactions, emoji="")
    contro = get(message.reactions, emoji="")
    flore = get(message.reactions, emoji="")
    await message.add_reaction("")
    await message.add_reaction("")
    await message.add_reaction("")
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    print('temposcaduto')
    await ctx.send(f"{favore.count} a favore , {contro.count} contro e {flore.count} astenuti")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use fetch_message() to fetch the message again and get new reactions

```py
@client.command(aliases=["cr"])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def conteggio_reazioni(ctx, *, proposta):
    message = await ctx.send(proposta)
    await message.add_reaction("")
    await message.add_reaction("")
    await message.add_reaction("")
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    message = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(message.id)
    thumbsup = len([await i.users().flatten() for i in message.reactions if str(i.emoji) == ""][0])
    thumbsdown = len([await i.users().flatten() for i in message.reactions if str(i.emoji) == ""][0])
    neutral = len([await i.users().flatten() for i in message.reactions if str(i.emoji) == ""][0])
    
    print('temposcaduto')
    await ctx.send(f"{thumbsup} a favore , {thumbsdown} contro e {neutral} astenuti")
```